# Is SimpleDataFormat really inconsistent with times finer than milliseconds?

Tags: java

The following code snippet shows SimpleDateFormat working just fine with milliseconds, but inconsistently with an extra decimal place. (It comes from my data source, and the extra digit is always zero.)

```
// working as expected with milliseconds
try {
    String dateString = "03:15:28.142";
    String format = "hh:mm:ss.SSS";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date + "\t" + date.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// not working as expected with one extra decimal place
try {
    String dateString = "03:15:28.1420";
    String format = "hh:mm:ss.SSS0";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = new Date();
    // date to string works as expected
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    // string to date doesn't work at all
    System.out.println(date + "\t" + date.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is

```
09:23:07.545
Thu Jan 01 03:15:28 EST 1970    29728142
09:23:07.5490
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03:15:28.1420"
```

I can turn a date into a formatted string just fine, but I can't turn a string into a date.
I have a workaround, so this is a "nice to know" - but the apparent inconsistency bothers me.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is an error in your format that contains an extra **0**.

 Try to write format as bellow:

```
String format = "hh:mm:ss.SSS";
```

Comment: The extra 0 is certainly legal in creating the date string as non-A-Z characters are simply copied to the output. The JavaDoc for .parse says it is "lenient" on the format of its input, but gives no details on what that means…

Comment: @JohnHascall , I think ``SSS0`` is not a valid format for millisecond. Am I wrong?

Comment: formatter.format() doesn't care, characters which are not specifiers are simply copy to the output string (just like the colons and dot are).

Comment: String format = "hh:mm:ss.SSS"; works fine with just milliseconds - see first half of snippet. Parsing with the extra zero does not give a ParseException; it just gives the wrong result (10 times the value of the milliseconds).